# What should getBoundingClientRect() return for foreignObject XHTML elements embedded in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Consider an SVG document like this…

```xml
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="100%" height="100%" …>
  <g transform="rotate(45) skewX(10)">
    <foreignObject x="100" y="200" width="10" …>
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p id="foo">Hi Mom!</p>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

…and JavaScript code like this…

```js
console.log( document.getElementById('foo').getBoundingClientRect() );
```

Notice that:

- The `body` of the HTML document is offset in the SVG, and rotated, and skewed.
- The SVG is scaled so that 1 SVG unit is not the same as 1 screen pixel.

Should `getBoundingClientRect()` return the left/right/top/bottom of the screen-aligned bounding rectangle in the web browser?

Or should it return the coordinates of the object within the context of the `body`, and leave it up to the user to transform from the `foreignObject` space into the screen pixels for the scaled/rotated/skewed SVG?

*I'm not so much interested in your opinion of how this should behave as a clear interpretation of how the specifications involved dictate that this **shall** behave.*

Here's a simple example of this, showing that Chrome does the former while Firefox does the latter: http://phrogz.net/SVG/html_location_in_svg_in_html.xhtml

**Edit**: Here's the Webkit bug describing Chrome/Safari's incorrect handling of this test case: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Boris Zbarsky in [my (incorrect) bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700477#c2), the [CSSOM View Module spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods) says:

> *The `getClientRects()` and `getBoundingClientRect()` methods provide information about the position of the border box edges of an element relative to the viewport.*

…and the specification [elsewhere](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#terminology) explicitly defines *viewport* as:

> *[...] defined by CSS 2.1 unless there is an ancestor `foreignObject` element in the http://www.w3.org/2000/svg namespace in which case that element acts as viewport and initial containing block*.

In summary, `getBoundingClientRect()` called on an HTML element inside a `<foreignObject>` in an `<svg>` element should return the bounding box of the element within the viewport specifically for the HTML body; it is up to the scripter to transform from this into screen space, if desired.

Comment: "it is up to the scripter to transform from this into screen space, if desired" — Desired! any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: @oluckyman On the `foreignObject` itself, you can call both `getBoundingClientRect()` and `getBBox()` (the latter returning the coordinates "with respect to the current SVG space"). Then e.g. calculate the scale factor `foreignObject.getBoundingClientRect().width/foreignObject.getBBox().width` and divide the measured dimensions of the HTML element by that scale factor to obtain the corrected dimensions.